# PCIe error while using Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: pcie

I recently bought a hardware and connected to the server through PCIe port. My device use Ubuntu 16.04.3 with kernel version 4.15.0-99-generic. The strange thing is every time when I start the server, the device can be detected for the first a few minutes, but after about 10 mins,the device can't be detected anymore. Below is part of the error info. So does anyone knows how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
[   18.027110] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
[  989.534123] pciehp 0000:66:02.0:pcie204: Slot(3-1): Link Down
[  989.534154] pciehp 0000:66:01.0:pcie204: Slot(2): Link Down
[  989.534183] pciehp 0000:66:00.0:pcie204: Slot(1): Link Down
[  989.537257] pciehp 0000:66:03.0:pcie204: Slot(4): Link Down
[ 1045.147094] {1}[Hardware Error]: Hardware error from APEI Generic Hardware Error Source: 0
[ 1045.147117] {1}[Hardware Error]: It has been corrected by h/w and requires no further action
[ 1045.147123] {1}[Hardware Error]: event severity: corrected
[ 1045.147130] {1}[Hardware Error]:  Error 0, type: corrected
[ 1045.147136] {1}[Hardware Error]:   section_type: PCIe error
[ 1045.147142] {1}[Hardware Error]:   port_type: 6, downstream switch port
[ 1045.147148] {1}[Hardware Error]:   version: 3.0
[ 1045.147154] {1}[Hardware Error]:   command: 0x0547, status: 0x0010
```

Comment: So what is the device?

Comment: Your description doesn't feel right; Ubuntu 16.04.3 used the 4.10 kernel (not 4.15; that was 16.04.5), so it maybe some of your details are incorrect, or your system isn't quite right... A fully updated Xenial system should report itself as 16.04.7 currently.   (*maybe 16.04.3 is the installation level, not what you're currently running, but your description shows issues with the system alone*)

Comment: thanks for the advice, i have already updated the system to 18.04 and it was fixed